# How to Iterate and Get React State Object Values?

Tags: reactjs, state, display

Here is my simple react component.

```
export default function App() {
  const [stats, setStats] = React.useState(() => {
    return {
      name: "",
      lvl: 1
    }})

  let displayStats; 
  for(let key in stats) {
    displayStats += <p>{key}</p>
  }

  return (
    <>
    {displayStats}
    </>
  )
}
```

This displayStats variable returns 'undefined[object Object][object Object]' on the screen. Why? What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
return (
   <>
      {Object.keys(stats).map(key => <p>{key}</p>)}
   </>
)
```

-> If you want to iterate through only values use Object.values(objName)

-> If you want to iterate through both values and keys use Object.entries(objName)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the key on the stats object.

**Change**

```js
displayStats += <p>{key}</p>
```

**To**

```js
displayStats += <p>{stats[key]}</p>
```